# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' has no attribute 'RETURN'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Why the error message is showing when I run the following code? I also used `ENTER` key instead of `RETURN`, but then error showed:

> "ImportError: cannot import name 'keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


PATH  = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.dr-chuck.com/csev-blog/?s=soup")
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element_by_id("s")
search.send_keys("soup")
search.send_keys(keys.RETURN)



try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))
    )
    articles = main.find_element_by_tag("article")
    for artiicle in articles:
        header = article.find_element_by_tag("a")
        print(header.text)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: It should be `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` (uppercase `Keys` after `import`), and then `Keys.RETURN` (uppercase `Keys`), like shown [in the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I got rid of that error, but now following error is showing. Can you please help me in this issue?  "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag'"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
```

It's should:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Note the uppercase **`K`** on **`Keys`**

Comment: Thanks brother . It worked. But I got a new problem. this following error is showing. Can you help me?  "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag'"

Comment: Change ```find_element_by_tag``` into ```find_element_by_tag_name```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

**from selenium.webdriver import Keys**
webElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Note the uppercase K on Keys